# Local center manifold theorem.

Tags: dynamical-systems

Local center manifold theorem, under certain assumptions, state that for the
\begin{cases}
\dot x = Cx+F(x,y) \\
\dot y = Py+G(x,y)\\
\end{cases}
there exist a function $h(x)$ such that
$$Dh(x)\left[Cx+F(x,h(x))\right]-\left[P\ h(x)+G(x,h(x))\right]=0$$
I noticed, doing exercises, that what one does is to develop the function $h(x)$ as
$$h(x)=a x^2+b x^3+...$$
My question is: why we start from the second order and not by first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absence of linear term in $$h(x) = ax^2 + bx^3 + \dots$$ means that curve $(x, h(x))$ is tangent to $Ox$ axis at origin. And that definitely makes sense when $E_{c}$ (a linear subspace which is spanned by eigenvectors of Jacobi matrix with purely imaginary or zero eigenvalues) coincides with $Ox$ axis too. Roughly speaking, local center (or stable/unstable) manifold is an invariant manifold which is tangent to $E_c$ (or $E_s$/$E_u)$ at origin. Moreover, this local manifold is a graph over $E_c$, you can take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1241375/a-differentiable-manifold-of-class-mathcalcr-tangent-to-e-pm-and-re/1241421#1241421) question for better understanding. If we suppose that 
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(0,0) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(0,0) = \frac{\partial G}{\partial x}(0,0) = \frac{\partial G}{\partial y}(0,0) = 0,$$
 then eigenvectors of Jacobi matrix just coincide with $Ox$ and $Oy$ axes. I think this explains pretty well why excercises suggest searching function of this form