# Investigate the stability of the origin for $\dot x=-y^2$, $ \dot y = -y + x^2 + xy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

I need to determine the stability of the origin of the following system of differential equations $$\pmatrix{\dot x \\ \dot y} = \pmatrix{-y^2 \\ -y + x^2 + xy},$$ using the Local Center Manifold Theorem as defined below.

> **Local Center Manifold Theorem**: Let ${\bf f} \in C^r(E)$, where $E$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ containing the origin and $r \ge 1$. Suppose that ${\bf f}({\bf 0}) = {\bf 0}$ and that $D{\bf f}({\bf 0})$ has $c$ eigenvalues with zero real parts and $s$ eigenvalues with negative real parts, where $c+s = n$. The system $\dot {\bf x} = {\bf f}({\bf x})$ then can be written in the diagonal form $$\begin{cases}\dot{\bf x} &= C{\bf x} + {\bf F}({\bf x}, {\bf y}) \\ \dot{\bf y} & = P{\bf y} + {\bf G}({\bf x}, {\bf y}),\end{cases}$$ where $({\bf x}, {\bf y}) \in \mathbb R^c \times \mathbb R^s$, $C$ is a square matrix with $c$ eigenvalues having zero real parts, $P$ is a square matrix with $s$ eigenvalues with negative real parts, and ${\bf F}({\bf 0}) = {\bf G}({\bf 0}) = {\bf 0}, D{\bf F}({\bf 0}) = D{\bf G}({\bf 0}) = O$; furthermore, there exists $\delta > 0$ and a function ${\bf h} \in C^r(N_\delta({\bf 0}))$ that defines the local center manifold $$W^c_{\text{loc}}({\bf 0}) = \{({\bf x}, {\bf y}) \in \mathbb R^c \times \mathbb R^s : {\bf y} = {\bf h}({\bf x}) \text{ for } |{\bf x}| < \delta\}$$ and satisfies $$D{\bf h}({\bf x})[C{\bf x} + {\bf F}({\bf x}, {\bf h}({\bf x}))] - P{\bf h}({\bf x}) - {\bf G}({\bf x}, {\bf h}({\bf x})) = 0$$ for $|{\bf x}| < \delta$; and the flow on the center manifold $W^c({\bf 0})$ is defined by the system of differential equations $$\dot {\bf x} = C{\bf x} + {\bf F}({\bf x}, {\bf h}({\bf x}))$$ for all ${\bf x} \in \mathbb R^c$ with $|{\bf x}| < \delta$.

I have begun to attempt to solve the problem, namely by letting $f({\bf x}) = \pmatrix{-y^2 \\ -y + x^2 + xy}.$ Then, $$D{\bf f}({\bf x}) = \pmatrix{0 & -2y\\2x + y & x - 1} \implies D{\bf f}({\bf 0}) = \pmatrix{0 & -2\\0 & -1},$$ which has eigenvalues of $0$ and $-1$. Thus, following the above theorem, $C = O$ and $P = [-1]$, as well as $F(x,y) = -y^2$ and $G(x,y) = x^2 + xy$ (just take the nonlinear part of the original systems).

Then the system is now in diagonal form.

**Here's where I am unfortunately stuck**. I'm trying to follow examples in my textbook **[like the one found here on the first page](https://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/wiki/images/f/f3/Cds140a-wi11-Week5NotesCMT.pdf)**. Almost magically, they come up with the next part which is the function $h$ with no explanation of *how* they come up with the terms that they do.

I understand that we omit the linear terms $1$ and $x$ because this would mean $(x,h(x))$ is tangent to the origin, as **[I have discovered here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1344331/227902)**. But how do I know what terms to include or even when to stop? I've been looking at some examples and sometimes they have an $xy$ term in there in addition to the powers of $x$, especially when the dimension of the system gets higher.

The reason being is that the next step is to plug $h(x) = ax^2 + bx^3 + \cdots$ into the equation we have above, i.e., $D{\bf h}({\bf x})[C{\bf x} + {\bf F}({\bf x}, {\bf h}({\bf x}))] - P{\bf h}({\bf x}) - {\bf G}({\bf x}, {\bf h}({\bf x})) = 0$ to find the unknown coefficients. Short of just *guessing* can anyone provide some insight on how we come up with the form of $h$? (short of just guessing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a Taylor series $y = a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + \ldots$ with, as you said, no $x^0$ or $x^1$ term.  Plug that in to the equation
for $\dot{x}$, and you get
$$ \dot{x} = -( a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + \ldots)^2 = -a_2^2 x^4 - 2 a_2 a_3 x^5 + \ldots $$
Thus
$$ \dot{y} = (2 a_2 x + 3 a_3 x^2 + \ldots) \dot{x} = - 2 a_2^3 x^5  - 7 a_2^2 a_3 x^6 + \ldots $$
But also 
$$ \dot{y} = - y + x^2 + x y =  \left( -a_{{2}}+1 \right) {x}^{2}+ \left( -a_{{3}}+a_{{2}} \right) {
x}^{3}+ \left( -a_{{4}}+a_{{3}} \right) {x}^{4}+ \left( -a_{{5}}+a_{{4
}} \right) {x}^{5}+ ( - a_6 + a_5) x^6 + \ldots$$
Equating coefficients of powers of $x$ and solving, we must have
$$ \eqalign{a_2 &= 1\cr
            a_3 &= a_2 = 1\cr
            a_4 &= a_3 = 1\cr
            a_5 &= a_4 + 2 a_2^3 = 3\cr
            a_6 &= a_5 + 7 a_2^2 a_3 = 10\cr} $$
etc.  You can take this to as many terms as you wish.

Comment: I see--it's a Taylor series of the function, and for good reason: my textbook says that it is extremely difficult, if not impossible to find what $h(x)$ is in real life. This actually clarifies quite a bit. I very much appreciate *this* solution because it allows me to see the problem worked from a different angle which has actually helped me make progress trying to fit the theorem.