# sketching the stable manifold

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I sketch the stable and unstable manifolds of the system 
$$u'=v$$ $$v' = 2u-u^3-v$$?

I know the definitions of the stable and unstable manifold, but I have no Idea how to even begin sketching it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Find saddle equillibria. Find their eigenspaces: (un)stable manifold is tangent to (un)stable eigenspace. Just plot something that is more or less compatible with tangency condition and with vector field. It works as a crude approximation.

Comment: Thankyou! I see how to do it now. But does that mean I can draw something that curves over and matches the spirals at $(\sqrt{2}, 0), (-\sqrt{2},0)$? Also, if you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Well, you can draw spirals just spiraling :) I'm a bit in a hurry now, so I prefer to try to give helpful directions in comments. I answered a [similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1241375/a-differentiable-manifold-of-class-mathcalcr-tangent-to-e-pm-and-re/1241421#1241421) (IMO) a while ago, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

A small MATHEMATICA script to draw the unstable manifold which is located along a section of

$$
v \approx -2u +\frac{u^3}{7}+\frac{3u^5}{539}
$$

```
n = 5;
V = Sum[a[k] U^k, {k, 1, n}];
res = D[V, U] V - 2 U + U^3 + V;
equs = CoefficientList[res, U];
sola = Solve[equs == 0, Table[a[k], {k, 1, n}]][[1]];
V0 = V /. sola

gr1 = StreamPlot[{v, 2 u - u^3 - v}, {u, -3, 3}, {v, -3, 3}];
gr2 = Plot[V0, {U, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}];
Show[gr1, gr2]
```

[image]